# Change value of variables based on condition

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using AlpineJS I need to change the values of 1 or 2 variables based on a condition:

```
<button x-on:click="step < 4 ? step++; step++; done=true">Done</button>
```

However this is not working. Can this be done inside `x-on:click`?

Comment: If that takes an expression, then something like `step < 4 ? step++ : (step++, done=true)` might work

Comment: @adiga is right; your ternary syntax is incorrect. You need a `:` after your first `step++`, rather than a `;`.

Comment: Or something like this: `++step && step > 4 && done=true`

Comment: ```<div x-data="{ step: 0 }">
    <button x-on:click="step < 4 ? step++:  step++; done=true">Done</button>
    <span x-text="step"></span>
  </div>```

Comment: step needs to be initialized with a value right?

Comment: Why is it not `step++; if() done=true;`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your ternary statement formatting may be causing an issue here.  I would first rule this out by changing the `;` to a `:`.
Additionally,I'm adding the step +=2 to replicate the ternary false conditional action. which by the looks of it you are trying to do? You may have to adjust the logic for this, as I found the function you are trying to accomplish unclear (a common problem with ternary statements).

`<button x-on:click="step < 4 ? step+=2 : step++; done=step > 4;">Done</button>`

I tested this method using `onclick` hook:

`<button onclick="step < 4 ? step+=2 : step++; done=step-1 > 4;">Done</button>`